# Java client to connect to SignalR?

Tags: java, .net, signalr

I'd like to connect to a SignalR-server from a java client. Is that possible?

Has anybody written a java-client to connect to SignalR?

Comment: +1. Thought about that in context of writing an Android native app, but I guess there's no Java client atm.

Comment: Too bad. Using it to build Android apps would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately, Java is not my native language. :) Do you know where I can find a description of the protocol used by SignalR?

Comment: I don't think there is a full description anywhere. It's changing quite frequently, so IMO there won't be a complete one before 1.0 airs. But having a brief description of at least the negotiation process and one of the transport methods would be good enough to have...

Comment: We'll start documenting the protocol pretty soon.

Comment: As an option you can use the Javascript client and access it from Java through DWR.

Comment: Another option would be expose .Net client as a SOAP-based webservice and access it from Java (JAX-WS)

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs  or have you found a good solution in the meantime?

Comment: I didnt find a solution so I started to develop one by myself. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didnt find a SignalR-client for Android so I started to develop one by myself.
You can checkit out at https://github.com/erizet/SignalA. <del>Curently it's more like a proof-of-concept than a finnished library.</del> It's now updated to protocol version 1.2 which is used in the 1.0 release of SignalR.

Comment: Hey Erik, I am in need of SignalR client for Java and I saw SignalA but the problem is that it does not (yet) support Hubs. Can you advice me what are my options?

Comment: I'm thinking of implementing Hubs...maybe. Another option is that you implement Hubs and contribute to the project. :)

Comment: Is there any tutorial available for the implementation of SignalA on Android?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has just released a java client https://github.com/SignalR/java-client even an Android client.

Comment: Thanks for the link! [I've written a short tutorial to get started with this client](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/), since the documentation still seems limited.

Comment: Great material, Steven!