# What's the current status of a Java port of SignalR client?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

As I understand there are plans to create Java SignalR client, any ideas when that will be done? I am currently using a JavaScript client to connect to Hubs from a web client, but I will need to expand that also to Android clients.

I saw that [Erik Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162003/erik-z) wrote a library https://github.com/erizet/SignalA which looks great but unfortunately it doesn't support Hubs. Is it worth extending it or official release is on the way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java client to connect to SignalR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089031/java-client-to-connect-to-signalr)

Comment: Microsoft has released a Java client earlier this month [as pointed out by an answer in a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22441784/590790).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no set release date for a supported SignalR Java Client.  I'd recommend continuing your search for third party Java clients or potentially building your own.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented hubs in [SignalA](http://github.com/erizet/SignalA) now!